# Convert integer to dates in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-datetime

Is there aby way of converting integers of range(0,365) to dates (dtype='datetime64[D]')?
Eg:
0 -> 1 jan
1 -> 2 jan
.
.
31 -> 1 feb
.
.
364-> 31 dec

P.S: I don't need the year. Only date and month for a non-leap year.

Comment: Relative to the current year? (What about `60`, should that map to February 29th or March 1st?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the mapping to be in a dictionary, this is how it would look:

```
import datetime
In [35]: days = {}

In [36]: for i in range(0, 365):
    ...:     days[i] = (datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(days=i)).strftime("%d %b")
    ...:
```

You'll get this:

```
In [37]: days
Out[37]: 
{0: '01 Jan',
 1: '02 Jan',
 2: '03 Jan',
 3: '04 Jan',

 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned that you need the resultset for a non-leap year so create the **datetime** object with a non-leap year such as '2015'

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
for day_count in range(0, 365) : 
    curr_date_object = datetime.strptime('2015-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d') + timedelta(days=day_count)
    print(curr_date_object.strftime("%d %b"))
```

This will return your desired result.

```
01 Jan
02 Jan
03 Jan
04 Jan
05 Jan
...
```